# What development stage do the version 0.13.99 nodes represent?

Tags: nodes, bitcoin-core-development

So, obviously Bitcoin Core 0.13.0 and 0.13.1 have been released, 0.13.2 is nearing release, and 0.14.0 will have its feature freeze in a few weeks. However, there are also some hundred odd nodes that show up as 0.13.99. What does that version represent?

Comment: I can see there is a release candidate for 0.13.2, but has it really been released?

Comment: @SvenWilliamson: Sorry, I was getting ahead of myself. You're correct, only the rc is out.

Comment: well it is out now :)

Answer (score 2):

While releases are carefully tested, tagged and then made available as executables, it is also possible to compile Bitcoin directly from the source code.

Bitcoin Core nodes that were built directly from a commit on the master branch instead of one of the releases show up as 0.XX.99, where XX is the latest major release.